Add conditional CSS to an interactive grid row based on an hidden column value
On an interactive grid (IG), I'm trying to add a background color to a row when the value of a hidden column is equal to 'Y'.
I tried multiple solutions, but none of them was working.

I set a static ID to my IG: igConcessions

I set a static ID to my hidden column (NIVELLEMENT_CONCE): conceNivelle

I created a dynamic action on page load which executes JavaScript code:
$(document).ready(function() {
    // I also tried to set the column name instead of the column ID
    $("#igConcessions td[headers='conceNivelle']").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().trim() === "Y") {
            $(this).closest("tr").css({'background-color': 'red'});
        }
    });
});

I also tried some other code:
// Sélectionnez toutes les lignes de la grille interactive
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("#igConcessions .a-GV-row");
rows.forEach(function(row) {
    // Trouver la colonne cachée avec la valeur 'Y' ou 'N'
    var hiddenColumn = row.querySelector("td[headers='conceNivelle']");
    if (hiddenColumn && hiddenColumn.textContent.trim() === 'Y') {
        // Ajouter la classe CSS pour colorier la ligne en rouge
        row.classList.add("highlight-red");
    }
});



None of these worked. How can I do it differently?

I think this post on oracle forums might help you. There is code to set the background for a cell conditionally. You could do it for all columns instead of for a row.
